# How to log SQL generated by EF using log4net

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, log4net

In my web project I'm using **EF6** and I'd like to log generated SQL for debugging purpose.

I'm also using log4net to handle logs, so I'm looking for a way to integrate them together.

What's the correct way to achieve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At the moment I'm using this approach: in my `BaseController` I have something like this:

```
public class BaseController
{
    protected MyDbContext DataContext { get; set; }
    protected readonly ILog logger;

    public BaseController()
    {
        DataContext = new MyDbContext();
        logger = LogManager.GetLogger(GetType());

        DataContext.Database.Log = (dbLog => logger.Debug(dbLog));

        // ...
    }

    //...

}
```

I don't know if this is the best way, but it works...

Comment: Is this an answer, or an addition to your question showing current code?

Comment: @CallumLinington this is the first solution I tried, are there better ways to achieve this?

Answer (score 4):

if someone after 2 years still searches for a solution:

the solution of @davioooh led me to something similar (if you probably use Entity Framework not with a WebApi, or don't want to use a `BaseController`-class):

Just when inheriting from `DbContext` you could also do this in the constructor:

```
public class MyContext:DbContext
{
    private readonly ILog _logger = LogManager.GetLogger(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);

    public MyContext()
           : base("<connectionstring>")
    {
        Database.Log = log => _logger.Debug(log);
    }
}
```