# Logging Sql queries in log file using EF core and Log4net

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, log4net

I'm trying to log SQL queries into a file using log4net and .NET Core (EF 3.1).

I tried the following configuration:

**Startup.cs**

```
loggerFactory.AddLog4Net();
```

**DBContext.s**

```
private readonly ILoggerFactory _loggerFactory;

 protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {

                    optionsBuilder.UseLoggerFactory(_loggerFactory);

        }
```

**log4netConfig:**

```
 <appender name="logger" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    <file value="c:\\log.txt" />
    <appendToFile value="true" />
    <rollingStyle value="Size" />
    <maximumFileSize value="100MB" />
    <maxSizeRollBackups value="3"/>
    <staticLogFileName value="true" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="[%thread] ; %date ; %property{ExcutionTime} ; %message%newline" />
    </layout>
    <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelRangeFilter">
      <levelMin value="DEBUG" />
      <levelMax value="DEBUG" />
    </filter>
  </appender>
```

I got an empty file as a result. What am I missing?

Comment: Which EF Core version? [EF Core 2.x and later already log](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/logging?tabs=v3) using the Microsoft.Extensions.Logging infractructure. How do you configure the DbContexts?

Comment: I'm using EF core 3.1 , as for dbContext configuration I used database first configuration @PanagiotisKanavos

Comment: BTW the examples show configuring logging *inside* a DbContext, but you can do the exact same thing with the  `AddDbContext` overloads that accept a `DbContextOptionsBuilder`. In `Startup` you have access to the configuration and services collection and any custom LoggerFactory

Comment: I meant, are you using `AddDbContext<>()`, `AddDbContext(builder=>...)`, or is all the configuration contained in `OnConfiguring`? Have you tried logging the way it's shown in the docs? Did you encounter a problem?

Comment: Ah sorry , yes also I'm using AddDBContext in startup.cs.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following within your DbContext class:

```
private readonly ILogging _logger = LogManager.GetLogger(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
public MyContext(): base("<connectionstring>")
{
    Database.Log = log => _logger.Debug(log);
}
```

There is already a quite similar answer that might help you further.
Take a look at the following:[How to log SQL generated by EF using log4net](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42066443/8293694)

Comment: in ef core there is nothing called Database.log as I know

Comment: As a matter of fact there is a Log property as a member of Database class
Check this out: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.database?view=entity-framework-6.2.0

Comment: @vasilisdmr above given documentation is for `EF6` and not for `Ef-Core` 3.1